Visual Studio keeps popping up error messages
I get these three error messages popping up everytime I boot up my current C# file. These three messages pop up and will always reappear shortly after being closed, hence blocking a good portion of the screen.
"The feature "Semantic Classification" is currently unavailable due to an internal error. Exit code 1073807364 Show stack monitoring
The feature "Runner for Diagnostic Analysis Tool" is currently unavailable due to an internal error. Exit code 1073807364 Show stack monitoring
The feature "Inheritance Margin" is currently unavailable due to an internal error. Exit code 1073807364 Show stack monitoring
PIC
The only solution so far is making a new C# Project, and like 50% of them will develop the issue I'd assume. I've had this issue also in the past, some files I keep working on somehow develop it after closing and reopening them. Chat GPT is of no use solving this too.

restarted the application
made sure Visual Studio is updated to the latest version


Did you try the following;

Updates extensions or disable them => "Extensions" > "Manage Extensions" > "Updates"
Reset visual studio settings => "Tools" > "Import and Export Settings" > "Reset all settings"
Check for the project settings
Check for memory/cpu utilization of your system

